# How to make a clean API call with axios when I need to be authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, api, get, axios, native

I'm working on React Native and I have to make calls to an API a coworker created. I have successfully made a POST call to authenticate, I have my access token (even if I don't know if it will be useful..) and my user's id. Now I want to make a GET call to get the user's datas but I'm stuck here.

The login route is :

```
Route::post('users/auth/login', function(Request $request) {

$data = $request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|string',
]);

$user = User::whereEmail($data['email'])->firstorFail();

if ($user) {
    if (!Hash::check($data['password'], $user->password)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
    }

    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
    'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    'expires_at' => Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString(),
    'user' => $user,
    ]);
}

});
```

the user's data route is :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

//Infos de l'Utilisateur connecté
Route::get('users/info', function () {
    return(User::where('id', Auth::id())->firstorFail());
});
}
```

and this works to authenticate :

```
axios.post("http://1.xx.xx.4:81/api/users/auth/login", {
    email: email,
    password: pass,
  },)
  .then((response) => {
     deviceStorage.saveItem("access_token", response.data.access_token);
     deviceStorage.saveItem("idUser", toString(response.data.user.id));
     this.newJWT(response.data.access_token);
     this.newJWT(response.data.user.id);
     this.setState({id: response.data.user.id});
     console.log("Connexion done.\n" + response + "\nUser's name = " + response.data.user.name + "\nUser's id = " + response.data.user.id);
}
```

I've tried something like this :

```
    axios.get('http://1.xx.xx.4:81/api/users/info')
      .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
      console.log("API done");
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
      console.log("API failed");
          console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(function () {
          // always executed
      console.log("API always");
      });
```

I tried with arguments in 'headers' too, but nothing worked...

I got this error when trying to get datas :

```
Request failed with status code 401
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18:6 in settle
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:59:13 in handleLoad
- node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43 in     dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:570:23 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:392:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter  \EventEmitter.js:191:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:349:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106:26 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:297:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

What i do is when the user is logged you set the global *Authorization* header in **axios** so all your requests has the token i do this in the index so in every view the headers configuration is updated:

```
const _token = window.localStorage.getItem( 'token' );

if( userIsLogged ){
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${ _token }`;
}
else {
// Your action if is not logged.
// I just remove localStorage Items
}
```